# how to create object using user input using array and not array list

Tags: java, arrays, bluej

When i compile and execute, I get `java.lang.ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. How do i fix it? Must use array and not arrayList. This is `BlueJ`. I'm inheriting the methods from desktop and laptop and those 2 classes are getting the values of parent class in computer.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testComputer {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String a;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Desktop[] desk = new Desktop[5];
        Laptop[] lap = new Laptop[5];
        int Desk = 0;
        int Lap = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("*************** Artificial Intelligence Co.***************");
            System.out.println("Computer Menu");
            System.out.println("1. Add a new Desktop Information");
            System.out.println("2. Add a new Laptop Information");
            System.out.println("3. Display all Computer Information");
            System.out.println("4. Quit");
            System.out.println("***********************************************************");
            System.out.print("Please enter either 1 to 4: ");
            a = scanner.nextLine();

            if (a.equals("1")) {
                desk[Desk] = new Desktop();
                desk[Desk].setDisplayDesktopInfo();
            } else if (a.equals("2")) {
                lap[Lap] = new Laptop();
                lap[Lap].setDisplayLaptopInfo();
            } else if (a.equals("3")) {
                int i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i <= desk.length; i++) {
                    if (desk.length == i) {
                        System.out.println("================Desktop================");
                        desk[i] = new Desktop();
                        desk[i].getDisplayDeskInfo();
                        System.out.println("");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Error!");
                    }
                }

                int j = 0;
                for (j = 0; j <= lap.length; j++) {
                    if (lap.length == j) {
                        System.out.println("================Laptop================");
                        lap[j] = new Laptop();
                        lap[j].getDisplayLapInfo();
                        System.out.println("");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Error");
                    }
                }
            } else if (a.equals("4")) {
                System.out.println("Good Bye!");
            }
        } while (!a.equals("4"));

    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Desktop extends Computer
{    
private static final String alphanumeric_regex_pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";
private String Monitor;

public Desktop()
{

}
void setMonitor(String monitor)
{
    Monitor = monitor;
}
String getMonitor()
{
    return Monitor;
}

void setDisplayDesktopInfo()
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("========================================");
    System.out.println("Information for new Desktop");
    System.out.println("========================================");
    System.out.print("What is the Computer ID: " + "");
    setComputerID(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.print("What is the Processor Speed: " + "");
    setprocessorSpeed(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.print("What is the RAM: " + "");
    setRAM(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.print("What is the Harddisk size: " + "");
    setHarddisk(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.print("What is the Monitor Type: " + "");
    setMonitor(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Your information has been added successfully.");
    System.out.print("");
}
void getDisplayDeskInfo()
{
    System.out.println("Computer ID: " + getComputerID());
    System.out.println("Processor Speed: " + getprocessorSpeed());
    System.out.println("RAM: " + getRAM());
    System.out.println("Harddisk: " + getHarddisk());
    System.out.println("Monitor: " + getMonitor());
    System.out.print("");
}
```

}

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Laptop extends Computer
{
private String Weight;

void setWeight(String weight)
{
    Weight = weight;
} 
String getWeight()
{
    return Weight;
}

void setDisplayLaptopInfo()
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("========================================");
    System.out.println("Information for new Laptop");
    System.out.println("========================================");
    System.out.print("What is the Computer ID: " + "");
    setComputerID(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.print("What is the Processor Speed: " + "");
    setprocessorSpeed(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.print("What is the RAM: " + "");
    setRAM(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.print("What is the Harddisk size: " + "");
    setHarddisk(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.print("What is the Weight: " + "");
    setWeight(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Your information has been added successfully.");
    System.out.print("");
}
void getDisplayLapInfo()
{
    System.out.println("Computer ID: " + getComputerID());
    System.out.println("Processor Speed: " + getprocessorSpeed());
    System.out.println("RAM: " + getRAM());
    System.out.println("Harddisk: " + getHarddisk());
    System.out.println("Weight: " + getWeight());
    System.out.print("");
}
```

}

```
*************** Artificial Intelligence Co.***************
Computer Menu
1. Add a new Desktop Information
2. Add a new Laptop Information
3. Display all Computer Information
4. Quit
***********************************************************
Please enter either 1 to 4: 1
========================================
Information for new Desktop
========================================
What is the Computer ID: D001
What is the Processor Speed: 3.3GHZ
What is the RAM: 4GB
What is the Harddisk size: 80GB
What is the Monitor Type: CRT

Your information has been added successfully.
*************** Artificial Intelligence Co.***************
Computer Menu
1. Add a new Desktop Information
2. Add a new Laptop Information
3. Display all Computer Information
4. Quit
***********************************************************
Please enter either 1 to 4: 3
If you see this message means you have not done yet!
If you see this message means you have not done yet!
If you see this message means you have not done yet!
If you see this message means you have not done yet!
If you see this message means you have not done yet!
Error
Error
Error
Error
Error
*************** Artificial Intelligence Co.***************
Computer Menu
1. Add a new Desktop Information
2. Add a new Laptop Information
3. Display all Computer Information
4. Quit
***********************************************************
Please enter either 1 to 4: 4
Good Bye!
```

Comment: `<= desk.length` and in other places - use `<` instead, arrays are *zero-based* in Java.

Comment: now i have no error but when i execute i have all error as input.

Error!
Error!
Error!
Error!
Error!
Error!
Error
Error
Error
Error
Error
Error

Comment: Then debug your code and you'll find the problem in less than 3 seconds.

Comment: @MarounMaroun This is bluej, it cannot debug

Comment: In both arrays (`desk`,`lap`), you are always writing on the same offset (0), because you don't increment `Desk` when the use chooses 1, and don't increment `lap` when the user chooses 2.

Comment: [Seems like one can debug in BlueJ just fine](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/02/BlueJ/BlueJ3.html).

Comment: `if(desk.length == i)` - this check doesn't make sense (and the one in the other loop) - what were you trying to do here?

Comment: @QuakeCore how can i increment?

Comment: @WeiXingNeo simply add `++Desk;` after `desk[Desk].setDisplayDesktopInfo();`, `++Lap;` after `lap[Lap].setDisplayLaptopInfo();`,

Comment: @QuakeCore after i insert what you told me to, i have the same results. i cant see display all information that i input while testing. No more ArrayOutOfBoundsException. But not getting the output i wanted

Answer (score 0):

If the user chooses 3 you are creating a new computer, laptop object before displaying the information, I removed those lines, and your code will obiously generate [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html), now this code is error-free and the rest is up to you, Enjoy.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testComputer {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String a;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Desktop[] desk = new Desktop[5];
        Laptop[] lap = new Laptop[5];
        int Desk = 0;
        int Lap = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("*************** Artificial Intelligence Co.***************");
        System.out.println("Computer Menu");
        System.out.println("1. Add a new Desktop Information");
        System.out.println("2. Add a new Laptop Information");
        System.out.println("3. Display all Computer Information");
        System.out.println("4. Quit");
        System.out.println("***********************************************************");
        System.out.print("Please enter either 1 to 4: ");
        a = scanner.nextLine();

        if (a.equals("1")) {
            desk[Desk] = new Desktop();
            desk[Desk].setDisplayDesktopInfo();
            ++Desk;
        } else if (a.equals("2")) {
            lap[Lap] = new Laptop();
            lap[Lap].setDisplayLaptopInfo();
            ++Lap;
        } else if (a.equals("3")) {
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < desk.length; i++) {

                    System.out.println("================Desktop================");

                    desk[i].getDisplayDeskInfo();
                    System.out.println("");

            }

            int j = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < lap.length; j++) {

                    System.out.println("================Laptop================");

                    lap[j].getDisplayLapInfo();
                    System.out.println("");

            }
        } else if (a.equals("4")) {
            System.out.println("Good Bye!");
        }
    } while (!a.equals("4"));

}
```

}

Comment: lap[j].getDisplayLapInfo(); <-- this thing leads to ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:100. So how do i solve it?

Comment: hmm how did you get to the index 100 anyways, your arrays sizes are 5, which means each array can contain up to 5 objects, but not more!

Comment: and how many laptop objects are you trying to add to your lap array ?!!

Comment: Alright i made some changes and it seems to have no more errors. But the display are all from System.out.println. Not from the data i input

Comment: well i only added 1 particulars of both laptop and desktop

Comment: then the problem is in your `setDisplayLapInfo()`, `setDisplayDesktopInfo();`, or the getters, you are not implementing those methods right...

Comment: erm.. I dont get what you mean. Can i just send you the code i type and kindly help me see what i need to change?

Comment: the implementation of the laptop class looks good to me, it should work, I still have no idea what the problem is, share the content of your console please.?

Comment: Alright I have shared the console. It display nicely there

Comment: @WeiXingNeo see the edits above, your problem has been solved!

Comment: Unfortunately i have a new error. It's NullPointerException:null >> desk[i].getDisplayDeskInfo();